# What does Hibernate PostInsertEventListener.requiresPostCommitHanding do?

Tags: java, hibernate

In [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PostInsertEventListener.html) it says:

> Does this listener require that after transaction hooks be registered?

Does this mean, that the listener will run before the transaction commit if we return `false` and after if we return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, when the `PostInsertEventListener` is registered as `EventType.POST_INSERT`, the method is not called at all and the listener is always executed **before** committing the transaction.

However, if the listener is registered as `EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT` the method is actually called and if it returns `true` the listener will be called **after** committing the transaction. If it returns `false` the listener will **not** be called at all.

Also, if the listener is of type `PostInsertEventListener` the `onPostInsert` method will be called regardless of whether the transaction was successful or not. If the listener is of type `PostCommitInsertEventListener` the `onPostInsert` method will only be called for successful transactions. Otherwise, the `onPostInsertCommitFailed` method is called.